# Create Sheets Based on Cell Value and other things that make it more complicated

Tags: excel, vba

If was calling into a radio show I'd say, "Long time listener...first time caller".  I have learned so much from this site for a long time, but have never had a scenario I could not find an answer to...until today.

I need to perform multiple steps within a loop and my mind just gets twisted in knots trying to figure out how to do it because I need to pull stuff from different columns in different sheets within the same loop.  I hope the brilliant minds here can bring some order to the chaos!

Note: I know how to do most of these things individually in a vacuum.  It's all of it together...with all of the conditions...that has me flummoxed such that I just don't know where to start.

What I need to do is:

Look in a worksheet named "Data"
Create a new worksheet for each value in column B of that "Data" worksheet (not including row 1/headers) and name the worksheet the same thing.

THEN on the worksheet we just created, copy/paste all data (complete range w/headers) from another existing worksheet WHERE the worksheet name = the value in column A of the same row we just looked at above AND copy some other data from the "Data" sheet to the new sheet as well. *head spinning!*

Example of the "Data" sheet:  Well, it wouldn't let me insert an image because I don't have enough reputation points.  Here's a link to the example image.  [CLICK HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jdp8pcwr6dyenaj/Capture.JPG?dl=0)

The first new sheet created would be named "BBB" (taken from B2). Then, using other data from the first row, we want to find the sheet named "Brown" (taken from E2) that already exists in the workbook.  Copy everything from "Brown" and paste it to the new "BBB" sheet

Now, while still on this row in the loop, having just populated the new sheet, we want to now copy the value from the A2 ("Big Brown Ball") to the new sheet ("BBB") at F2 and fill it down the entire range for that column (as if I double-clicked the cell handle).

THEN, at long last, we can loop back to the next row of "Locations" sheet and repeat the same process until we run out of populated rows.

I'm so sorry at the complexity of this explanation, but that's the exact reason why I found myself needing to ask the question!  I just couldn't wrap my head around it.

Any help would be supremely appreciated!!!

EDIT: The responder below asked good questions as his head was spinning too!  My answers may be helpful to others as well.

Comment: What part of it are you having trouble with? I mean have you tried anything? Let us focus on specific issue rather than solve and create everything for you. If I understand it correctly (I already felt dizzy on the later parts), you just need one loop. Again if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Hehe.  Welcome to my dizziness!  I know how to accomplish creating new sheets, how to name them, and moving data from an existing sheet to another existing sheet.  It's the complexity of referencing so many different locations based on what's in a certain cell to get to the final product -- and using other values to determine what goes where (all of the "if this..then that")-- yep, that's where I get dizzy and just stare at my monitor not knowing where to start.  To answer your other question, yes, it's just one big loop with a lot of nested "stuff".

Comment: Ok why not just rename the sheets and then fill the Column F after that? Why do you have to copy everything? Do you need to preserve the original sheet somehow? Btw, I felt dizzy on how you construct your question. You should have at least provided what you've tried (your code) and along with it the parts which you can't get to work.

Comment: Another good question.  It's because there are 6 existing sheets from which the data is being copied to 45 new sheets (that's the real total...my example just had 3) depending on what data each new sheet is supposed to receive...which is based on the Column A value of each row in the loop.  The existing sheets act as master data sources and need to remain in their current form.  The new sheets just receive a copy of the data form whichever sheet applies to it. The new sheets will later be extracted as their own workbook to certain people.  I already know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range, lrow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set r = .Sheets("Data").Range("B2", "B4")
        For Each c In r
            .Sheets(c.Offset(0, 3).Value).Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            With ActiveSheet
                .Name = c
                lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("F2:F" & lrow).Value = c.Offset(0, -1)
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Is this what you're trying? HTH.

Comment: Wow, that is some seriously efficient code! And I even understand the logic...I think.  The one thing I don't grasp is the .Range("B2", "B4) at the top. Just tried to run by step-in to figure it out, but I get a Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range which debugs to the first line within the loop .Sheets(c.....  any ideas?

Comment: @rushjc **Range("B2", "B4")** from data sheet is where you get the sheet names right? In your sample screen shot (that is where BBB, SMC, TGB are). That's just another form of **Range("B2:B4")**. I hard coded it but you can make it dynamic. You will get a runtime if what's written in **Column E** is not exactly the same as your existing *Master Sheets Name* (which are Brown, Red, Green etc) since excel cannot copy a sheet that does not exist.

Comment: You were exactly right.  There was a typo in the first master.  Wow, I cannot thank you enough for sticking with me on this.  I could have *never* pulled that off in 11 lines of code.  Amazing!

Comment: @rushjc Cool. Glad it helped. Btw, try to construct better questions next time. Questions in long paragraphs are often closed. It is ok to explain but don't forget to include the things you've tried so we can focus on specific issues. Also simple illustrations could help.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks for the tip.  I'm so used to being the reader/learner and not the asker here. Again, thanks so much.  I'm truly in awe that this could be done in 11 lines!!!

Comment: @rushjc Well, first you need to find out how you'd do it manually the fastest way? So copying sheet and renaming it is faster than creating a new sheet and copying the contents from another then rename it. Then to get an idea on how you'll write your code, record a macro while doing the fastest manual steps. And there you have it. Clean the recorded macro code and your done.